# Interpretation of Beta Family in Generalized Additive Model (GAM)

Tags: r, regression, generalized-additive-model, beta-distribution, mgcv

My code for generalized additive model with the beta family.

```
library(mgcv)
df['outcome'][df['outcome'] == 1] <- 0.99
df['outcome'][df['outcome'] == 0] <- 0.01
mod <- gam(outcome ~ s(stage, k = 4, fx = TRUE), data = df, family = betar(link="logit"), method = "REML")
summary(mod)
plot(mod,
     trans=plogis,
     shift=coef(mod)[1],
     main = "Beta GAM Shifted Intercept")
```

Output

```
Family: Beta regression(0.73) 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
outcome ~ s(stage, k = 4, fx = TRUE)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.78702    0.06101   -12.9   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
         edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value
s(stage)   3      3  0.844   0.839

R-sq.(adj) =  -0.00323   Deviance explained = 26.7%
-REML = -590.92  Scale est. = 1         n = 431
```

[image]

First question, does the plot mean that

```
In stage 2, I have around 33% chance of getting the outcome?
```

Am I interpreting the plot correctly?

Second question, how do I interpret a a negative r-squared when the `deviance explained` is positive?

I am still trying to learn GAM and would appreciate some advice. Thanks!

Comment: A comment and a question...first, it's best to ignore the adjusted R-square and just interpret the deviance explained when using non-Gaussian models, as typical sums of squares approaches to approximating the variance explained in a model are not as useful. Second, what is stage here? Is it a factor or is it some discrete variable?

Comment: Thanks for your comments @ShawnHemelstrand, stage is a form of `timeline` measure

Comment: So am I correct in assuming that these are discrete time points? As in Stage 1 versus Stage 2? The reason I ask is because your model is treating this variable as continuous from what I see (as in Stage 1, Stage 1.5, etc.)

Comment: Good point @ShawnHemelstrand, `stage 1` signifies `week 1`, `stage 1.5 `signifies  `week 1.5`. I treat time as a continuous variables in this case on purpose as I would like to see the outcome for week 1, week 1.5, week 2, week 2.5, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you correctly read the meaning of the central line in your plot which is the $\mu(x)$ given your relatively simple model. Whether $\mu$ is a probability depends on what your data represents. Just to make sure: If your data can be represented as the outcomes of Bernoulli experiments, then you should use a logistic (or some other binomial) model.

However the confidence interval around it is probably not what you want, since it only represents the uncertainty around the spline and ignores the uncertainty around the intercept!

To demonstrate and present how to do this better with the `predict` function I'll build on the example from `help(betar)`

```r
library(mgcv)

set.seed(3);n<-400
dat <- gamSim(1,n=n)
mu <- binomial()$linkinv(dat$f/4-2)
phi <- .5
a <- mu*phi;b <- phi - a;
dat$y <- rbeta(n,a,b) 
# sort by x0 to plot lines
dat <- dat[order(dat$x0), ]

# simplified the model to one spline, so that it fits the question
bm2 <- gam(y~s(x0),family=betar(link="logit"), data=dat)

summary(bm2)
plot(bm2, pages=1, trans=plogis,
     shift=coef(bm2)[1],
     ylim = c(0.45, .6)  # fixing ylims to make plots comparable
     )
```

This mirrors your setup:

[image]

Now i solve the question using `predict`

```r
pred_dat <- predict.gam(bm2, se.fit = T)
z_a <- qnorm(.975)

plot(dat$x0, plogis(pred_dat$fit), type = "l", ylim = c(.45, .6))
lines(dat$x0, plogis(pred_dat$fit + z_a * pred_dat$se.fit), lty = 2)
lines(dat$x0, plogis(pred_dat$fit - z_a * pred_dat$se.fit), lty = 2)
```

Now here the confidence intervals are much wider since we include the uncertainty around the intercept and its covariance with the coefficients of the spline, see `vcov(bm2)`.

[image]

If you build a model where the intercept is predetermined instead of estimating it will look a lot like the 1st plot:

```r
# -1 in the formula means no intercept
bm3 <- gam(y~s(x0) - 1, offset = rep(coef(bm2)[1], n),family=betar(link="logit"), data=dat)
summary(bm3)

pred_dat <- predict.gam(bm3, se.fit = T)
plot(dat$x0, plogis(pred_dat$fit + coef(bm2)[1]), ylim = c(.45, .6), type = "l")
lines(dat$x0, plogis(pred_dat$fit + coef(bm2)[1] + z_a * pred_dat$se.fit), lty = 2)
lines(dat$x0, plogis(pred_dat$fit + coef(bm2)[1] - z_a * pred_dat$se.fit), lty = 2)
```

[image]

Looking at your plot specifically I can tell from the dashes into the plot area, that you only have data at the full weeks. If you want to have a nice interpolation you will have to specify the `newdata` argument, if you want a smooth interpolation. Also with only 4 distinct weeks, 3 edf on your spline + an intercept your model is pretty much identical to just using factors.

In regards to the 2nd question, I agree with @ShawnHemelstrand comment.